# Reading file to ArrayList

Tags: java, text, input

I'm trying to write a .dat file to an ArrayList. The file contains lines formatted like this : #name#,#number#.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("file.dat"));
while(s.hasNext()){
    String string = s.next();
    names.add(string.split(",")[0];
    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(string.split(",")[1];
}
```

If I check if it runs with printing, all I get is the first line.

Comment: How do you check if it runs? Are you running it in an IDE and stopping on a breakpoint?

Comment: I just add e print command for everything, like I print string, followed by the splitted strings...

Comment: can you show you exact data format

Comment: if the format is really "#name#,#number# you get an exception because you try to parse #number# to an int. If your format is name,442 it works for me as expected for the whole file

Comment: I'm curious, someone have an answer using the Java 8 Sream API ?

Comment: check my answer if that is what your require..i am not sure about your text file exactly so guessed it done..if you can provide exact textfile it woul be helpful

Comment: You're missing quite a few closing brackets at the end of your function calls to `add` and `parseInt` is this just a typo on here or also in your code? Or is Java now adding those itself before a semicolon?

Comment: ^^ but he says he is getting first line so something is working..its a typo here in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With standard Java libraries** (full code example):

```
BufferedReader in = null;
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {   
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        myList.add(str);
        //Or split your read string here as you wish.
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**With other common libraries:**

A one-liner with [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/file.txt"), "utf-8");
```

The same with [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<String> lines = 
     Files.readLines(new File("/path/to/file.txt"), Charset.forName("utf-8"));
```

Then you can iterate over the read lines and split each String to your desired ArrayLists.

Comment: Since Java 7 there is this nice one liner in the standard libraries to read a file: `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("abc.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `Scanner`, use a `BufferedReader`. The `BufferedReader` provides a method to read one line at a time. Using this, you can process every line individually by splitting them (`line.split(",")`) , stripping the trailing hashes, then pushing them into your `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I read a file and turn it into a arraylist

```
    public List<String> readFile(File file){
    try{
        List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            if(line != null){
                out.add(line);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        return out; 
    }
    catch(IOException e){

    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I try your method I keep heving the same problem. If I print out the name and number, I only get the first one, but when I remove the lines concerning the lists, everthing gets printed

Answer (score 0):

May be this is lengthy way but works:

**text file:**

```
susheel,1134234
testing,1342134
testing2,123455
```

**Main class:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Equal {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        List<Pojo> data= new ArrayList<Pojo>();
        String currentLine;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\test.dat"));
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] arr = currentLine.split(",");
                Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
                pojo.setName(arr[0]);
                pojo.setNumber(Long.parseLong(arr[1]));
                data.add(pojo);
            }
            for(Pojo i : data){
                System.out.print(i.getName()+" "+i.getNumber()+"\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

**POJO class:**

```
public class Pojo {    
    String name;
    long number;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
    public long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }    
    public void setNumber(long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```